# Does this sequence converge? And if so to what?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$a_{n}=\frac{2^nn!\cos\left(n^5\right)}{n^n}$$

Any ideas on this? Does it even converge?

Comment: It goes to $0$.

Answer (score 6):

use that $$\left|\frac{2^nn!\cos(n^5)}{n^n}\right|\le \frac{2^n n!}{n^n}$$ and this tends to zero for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: Or you can also use that if $a_n$ is bounded and $b_n$ goes to $0$ then $a_n b_n$ also goes to $0$.

Comment: this is a good idea!

Comment: Thank you both of you!